# i am trying to get the access_token dynamically from frontend using react js for the API.But i am getting CORS MISSING ALLOW ORIGIN error

Tags: javascript, azure, powerbi, webapi

i am trying to get the access_token dynamically from frontend using react js for the API

"**GET [https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token**"](https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token**%22)

by giving body parameters as

```
client_id:
client_secret:
scope:
grant_type:
redirect_uri:
```

But i am getting CORS MISSING ALLOW ORIGIN error .
How can i solve it ?

Is there any option to enable cors origin from react js ?

here is my method

```js
const mockSignIn = async () => {
  try {
    const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${DirectoryORtenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
    // const tokenUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.1&authorization_endpoint=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`;

    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    };

    const body = new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      scope: "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default",
      client_id: clientId,
      client_secret: clientSecret,
    });

    // const body = new URLSearchParams();
    // body.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    // body.append('scope', 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default');
    // body.append('client_id', clientId);
    // body.append('client_secret', clientSecret);

    // const body = new URLSearchParams()
    // body.append('client_id', clientId);
    // body.append('client_secret', clientSecret);
    // body.append('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    // body.append('resource', 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default');

    const tokenResponse = await axios.get(tokenUrl, body, { headers });

    console.log("access token = " + tokenResponse.data.access_token);
    console.log("access token = " + JSON.stringify(tokenResponse));

    setAccessToken(tokenResponse.data.access_token);
    return tokenResponse.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: It's not allowing you to do that because having a client secret in the front-end means anyone who can see the HTML and Javascript can get the client secret. It's not secure. You need to acquire the token in a back-end or authenticate the current user and call the API on their behalf.